# SQL Server : connection gets closed

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm running an application that needs to keep an open connection to a SQL Server database in order to do some checks/edits.

There are at least 10 queries per second atm and i expect them to go up as time passes.

I opted for one open connection to the database to reduce the timeout caused by opening a connection.

However, it seems that lately the connection gets closed, contrary to my belief that if I keep an open connection it stays that way.

The application is written in C#.

As a workaround I'm thinking of using 2-3 connections, to prevent data loss :

check if connection 1 is available, if it isn't do the same thing for connection 2 and so on.

Any ideas why my connection gets closed?

Comment: You can set some 'autoclose' type behaviour with ADO.Net, but without some code, it's hard to provide a specific answer. Be wary of Using blocks, as these will dispose connections.

Comment: Frankly, due to connection pooling being enabled by default, you might be better advised to just keep each connection local to the code that uses it, via "using" blocks and Open(). 10 ops per second is not high. I can't tell you how many connections we Open() per second on stackoverflow, or how many ops per second - but: much much higher than that. The connection pooling means it uses very few underlying connections, and detects zombies correctly etc.

Comment: Are your connection objects privately scoped?

Comment: @DavidOsborne Here's the code for the MSSQL queries : http://pastebin.com/X1UdjzPV

I'm a little paranoid about performance. If you look at the code you can see it's some kind of exploit prevention application.

Looking though the error logs it seems that the s_RohanGame is closed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed || con.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
{
            con.Open()
}
```

this code valuable to you

Comment: I didn't ask for code, i asked for reasons.
But thanks anyway.